# pnpm peer dependencies auto-install

Tags: javascript, node.js, eslint, vite, pnpm

How (or on which file) to set true to do auto install dependencies ?

my terminal error:

[image: my terminal error]

> hint: If you want peer dependencies to be automatically installed, set
> the "auto-install-peers" setting to "true". hint: If you don't want
> pnpm to fail on peer dependency issues, set the
> "strict-peer-dependencies" setting to "false".

```
auto-install-peers = true
```

Comment: create a file ".npmrc" in root directory of your project and set this flag.--------------- .
pnpm config set auto-install-peers true ----------------------------------------------------.
pnpm installs peer deps only after 7.1.4 version, Update pnpm in your machine. https://pnpm.io/installation

Answer (score 76):

pnpm uses npm's configuration formats. Hence, you should set configuration the same way you would for npm:

```
pnpm config set auto-install-peers true
```

**Note:** The above command uses the default config location which stores the setting for the local user account (at `~/.npmrc` for linux, or at `%USERPROFILE%\.npmrc` for Windows). To store the setting inside your project in a `.npmrc` file that can be checked in to version control, you can use the method pointed out by @ZoltanKochan, or equivalently append `--location project` to the command:

```
pnpm config set auto-install-peers true --location project
```

Comment: how to remove this configuration? and also this didn't update the dependency listed in the package.json when peers installed

Comment: @BryanLumbantobing `pnpm config delete auto-install-peers` would remove the setting (or you can manually edit the corresponding `.npmrc` file. I edited the answer to clarify this). But you shouldn't expect `package.json` to be updated when setting a config value or installing the dependencies. We're just telling pnpm to install the [peer dependencies](https://nodejs.org/en/blog/npm/peer-dependencies/).

Comment: is that a best practice? I see that `npm` also does that. it automatically installs peersDeps without the need to list the peerDeps in our package.json. but `yarn` doesn't

Comment: I'm not sure if I could quite grasp your point, and I'm not into developing js plugins, but generally, AFAIK, best practice is to avoid depending on modules that you don't explicitly declare in your `package.json`, since it might break sometihng on dependency updates. npm has decided to flatten the deps into `node_modules` root, and to somehow mix up everything in there (including peerDeps) and allow you to use them undeclared. If you want to do the same with pnpm, you need to "[shamefully-hoist](https://pnpm.io/npmrc#shamefully-hoist)" them :D

Comment: pnpm, by default, only installs (links) peerDeps if they have already been installed by some other dep.

Answer (score 34):

You need to create a `.npmrc` at the root of your project with the following content:

```
auto-install-peers=true
```

The answer from mrmashal will work also but only for you locally. So, when someone else fetches your repository, they will not have the peers automatically installed.

Answer (score 18):

### npm from v7 does auto-install, pnpm doesn't

**npm** starting **from v7**. Does install Peer Dependencies automatically https://github.com/npm/rfcs/blob/main/implemented/0025-install-peer-deps.md.

**pnpm doesn't do it automatically. Even at this stage.**
https://github.com/pnpm/pnpm/discussions/3995#discussioncomment-1893230

npm does the same way only with `.npmrc`

```bash
auto-install-peers = true
```

> auto-install-peers=true now makes pnpm work the same way as npm v7. From pnpm v7.1.3 ([ref](https://github.com/pnpm/pnpm/discussions/3995#discussioncomment-2797582))

And the with `.npmrc` and `not automatic` was a choice by the developers involved. There are those who were for and who weren't. ([ref1](https://github.com/pnpm/pnpm/discussions/3995#discussioncomment-1647428), [ref2](https://github.com/pnpm/pnpm/discussions/3995#discussioncomment-1893230))

### .npmrc

To do it you have to create a `.npmrc` file and add:

```yaml
auto-install-peers = true
```

This is the best way. Because it creates consistency for all developers consuming the project and repo. Same config.

So in simplified terms, if you have some packages that require peers just add the config. You have a nice warning that reminds you in case there are packages with `peer-dependencies`.

https://github.com/pnpm/pnpm/discussions/3995#discussioncomment-2797582

> auto-install-peers=true now makes pnpm work the same way as npm v7. From pnpm v7.1.3

#### Does an `--auto-install-peers` arg exists ? (No)

There is no `--auto-install-peers` arg.

Can check here the feature ask here https://github.com/pnpm/pnpm/issues/5284

Denied.

And the why is understandable. `.npmrc` is better for consistency. So that people `pnpm install` and it always works the same. No forgetting anything.

### Using install-peerdeps

> I advise using `.npmrc`. -> Native. straight forward.

> Note: you may consider this tool. If you fall into some of pnpm bugs (ex: [1](https://github.com/pnpm/pnpm/issues/5319), ) and inconsistencies with peer-dependencies handling. Many issues are open. I would go with `.pnpmrc first`. If any issues. I would use this tool.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/install-peerdeps

`install-peerdeps` supports pnpm.

The tool is mentioned in `eslint-config-airbnb` for example.

Example:

```bash
npx install-peerdeps --pnpm <your-package>

# or

npx install-peerdeps -P <your-package>

# as dev dep
npx install-peerdeps -P -D <your-package>

# Peers only
npx install-peerdeps -P -D --only-peers <your-package>
# or
npx install-peerdeps -P -D -o <your-package>
```

The package will automatically add the dependencies to `package.json` in `dependencies` or `devDependencies` depending on the used flag.

Answer (score 8):

Remove the node modules by running:

```
rm -rf node_modules
```

Then again run:

```
pnpm install
```

Comment: First create .npmrc with `auto-install-peers=true` set. Then `rm -rf node_modules` and finally pnpm install. I believe pnpm caches the config so we need to delete the node_modules so it re-caches again.

Answer (score 6):

I had to create `.npmrc` at the root of the project with `auto-install-peers=true`, then delete the `pnpm-lock.yaml` file and run `pnpm i --shamefully-hoist`