# `hardhat` support for `pnpm`

Tags: node.js, npm, hardhat, pnpm

Trying to use `hardhat` via `pnpm`.

With command:

> pnpm add -D @nomicfoundation/hardhat-toolbox

Get following error:

```
devDependencies:
+ @nomicfoundation/hardhat-toolbox 1.0.2

 WARN  Issues with peer dependencies found
.
├─┬ @nomicfoundation/hardhat-toolbox 1.0.2
│ ├── ✕ missing peer @ethersproject/abi@^5.4.7
│ ├── ✕ missing peer @ethersproject/providers@^5.4.7
│ ├── ✕ missing peer @nomicfoundation/hardhat-network-helpers@^1.0.0
│ ├── ✕ missing peer @nomicfoundation/hardhat-chai-matchers@^1.0.0
│ ├── ✕ missing peer @nomiclabs/hardhat-ethers@^2.0.0
│ ├── ✕ missing peer @nomiclabs/hardhat-etherscan@^3.0.0
│ ├── ✕ missing peer @types/chai@^4.2.0
│ ├── ✕ missing peer @types/mocha@^9.1.0
│ ├── ✕ missing peer @types/node@>=12.0.0
│ ├── ✕ missing peer @typechain/ethers-v5@^10.1.0
│ ├── ✕ missing peer @typechain/hardhat@^6.1.2
│ ├── ✕ missing peer chai@^4.2.0
│ ├── ✕ missing peer ethers@^5.4.7
│ ├── ✕ missing peer hardhat-gas-reporter@^1.0.8
│ ├── ✕ missing peer solidity-coverage@^0.7.21
│ ├── ✕ missing peer ts-node@>=8.0.0
│ ├── ✕ missing peer typechain@^8.1.0
│ └── ✕ missing peer typescript@>=4.5.0
└─┬ hardhat 2.11.1
  ├── ✕ missing peer ts-node@"*"
  └── ✕ missing peer typescript@"*"
Peer dependencies that should be installed:
  @ethersproject/abi@^5.4.7                        @types/mocha@^9.1.0                              
  @ethersproject/providers@^5.4.7                  @types/node@>=12.0.0                             
  @nomicfoundation/hardhat-chai-matchers@^1.0.0    chai@^4.2.0                                      
  @nomicfoundation/hardhat-network-helpers@^1.0.0  ethers@^5.4.7                                    
  @nomiclabs/hardhat-ethers@^2.0.0                 hardhat-gas-reporter@^1.0.8                      
  @nomiclabs/hardhat-etherscan@^3.0.0              solidity-coverage@^0.7.21                        
  @typechain/ethers-v5@^10.1.0                     ts-node@>=8.0.0                                  
  @typechain/hardhat@^6.1.2                        typechain@^8.1.0                                 
  @types/chai@^4.2.0                               typescript@>=4.5.0                               

Progress: resolved 294, reused 284, downloaded 0, added 1, done
```

I've seen several other packages that doesn't work with `pnpm` too before.

So, what's the reason cause such issue, is it `pnpm` or specific packages (e.g `hardhat`) responsible for such issue?

I really prefer to use `pnpm`, because it's much quicker than `npm`.

Comment: Peer dependencies are things the library needs but inspects you to install. Nothing pnpm specific about that

Comment: But there is no such issue when use npm.

Comment: Some versions of NPM automatically install peerDependencies, but pnpm doesn't by default.  You can choose this behavior though: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72468635/pnpm-peer-dependencies-auto-install

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the command:

```
pnpm config set auto-install-peers true
```

After that, just repeat your command and it will automatically install all the dependencies.

Comment: That seem to work, I put `auto-install-peers=true` into `.npmrc`.