# Install Eslint config airbnb dependencies with 'pnpm' in Astro React project

Tags: pnpm, eslint-config-airbnb

We are using `pnpm` as our package manager inside our Astro React project.

I need to setup [Eslint config Airbnb](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-config-airbnb).

In the readme it says use `npx install-peerdeps --dev eslint-config-airbnb` to install all dependencies.

How do I do that with `pnpm`?

Answer (score 1):

Actually you can use pnpm built in functionality to install dependency with peers.

[Related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72468635/pnpm-peer-dependencies-auto-install)

Execute this in your project directory.

```bash
pnpm config set auto-install-peers true --location project
```

It will create `.npmrc` file with option `auto-install-peers=true`
Then delete `pnpm-lock.yaml` and run

```
pnpm add -D eslint-config-airbnb
pnpm i
```

To install dependencies with peers